# error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to char[] charValue = Input.charAt(0);

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I need a program that takes in 4 integer inputs, 4 double inputs, and 3 character inputs. I have the integer and double inputs ready. I really need help getting the character inputs, please help.

I keep getting this error:

> incompatible types: char cannot be converted to char[]                       charValue = Input.charAt(0);

Here's my code:

```
int[] intValues = new int[4];
double[] floatValues = new double[4]; 
char[] charValue = new char[3];
String Input;


Input = stdin.readLine();
String[] charValues = Input.split("\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i < charValues.length; i++)
    Input = charValues[i];
    charValue = Input.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing braces in your loop, and you should assign each `char` to some index of the char array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < charValues.length; i++) {
    Input = charValues[i];
    charValue[i] = Input.charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it works. Thank You! I was seriously overthinking this.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because you are a=trying to assign a single character to character array.
It should be like this
charValue[index] = Input.charAt(0);